# Figuring out where Android stores files

Tags: java, android, file

I am writing to a file in my application. I want to find the file to check that the file has been written correctly (and so I can access the file via a web view). Here is the code I am using to write the file:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("rules.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(content.getBytes());
    fos.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and then I use this to get the directory of the file:

```
getFilesDir()
```

However the string it provides is not available as a directory on the my device (hidden files are shown).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: should be data/data/your.package.name/files/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android writes your internal files to `/data/data/<your package name>/files/<filename>`. You cannot access this via a file browser or something unless you are rooted.

Comment: Is accesing it via a webview out of the question then?

Comment: @SamStone If the webview is part of your app then you can easily access it. Any app can access any file in its own internal storage directory